# Magick++ find out whether an image has transparency

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I'm trying to find out whether an Image (the Magick++-class) is opaque/has transparent pixels. My current test code looks like this:

```
    Image orig;
    orig.read(inputPath.c_str());

    bool hasAlpha = orig.alpha();
    printf("Alpha: %s %s\n", inputPath.c_str(), hasAlpha ? "yes" : "no");
```

This correctly outputs "no" for a jpg and "yes" for a png with transparency, but unfortunately also reports "yes" for a PNG with no transparent pixels.

With the command `identify -format '%[opaque]' image.png`, imagemagick is able to detect this correctly for all files, so it is able to find this out, but I'd like to avoid calling an external program for various reasons and I can't find no fitting method in the docs or via Google. How can I find this out in code via Magick++?

Thank you!

Comment: You have to test the mean of the alpha channel. If not equal to 1, it has transparency.  Checking for whether there is an alpha channel is not sufficient.

Comment: @fmw42 mean or better min.

Comment: Have you read https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php: _%[opaque] CALCULATED: is image fully-opaque?_

Comment: mean==1 is fully opaque. mean<1 has partial transparency. mean==0 is fully transparent.  %[opaque] I think does the same, i.e. tests if mean==1 or not. .

Comment: @fmw42 Do you know how to access this via code? I've looked through the class documentation at https://www.imagemagick.org/Mhttps://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.htmlagick++/Image++.html , but it does not have any lead on this (or I'm missing something).

@ThomasSablik Yes, I'm aware of this, but I have not found a way to access this from code and I wasn't able to find the relevant location in the source of `identify`.

Comment: No, I do not. I do not code in any API, just the command line. But you can extract the alpha channel and then get the mean via fx or the equivalent or the equivalent of identify on the alpha channel to get the mean value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ImageMagick-7, I believe the method you need is `Magick::Image::isOpaque()`; which calls the same MagickCore method to calculate `'%[opaque]'`.

```cpp
bool hasAlpha = !orig.isOpaque();
printf("Alpha: %s %s\n", inputPath.c_str(), hasAlpha ? "yes" : "no");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way to find this out is by manually checking all pixels. My code is below, in case anyone else has this problem in the future. Two important things to note before using this:

- The method to check for an alpha channel seems to have been renamed to `alpha` in ImageMagick7 and was `matte()` before. Check your version if it does not compile.
- I only check for a missing alpha channel or transparency in the alpha channel. There are other transparency methods (i.e. setting a specific color as transparent) which I do not check for.

```
// assumed preamble:
//#include <Magick++.h>
//using namespace Magick;

/**
 * Finds out whether an image is opaque (has no transparent pixels). Tested for jpeg and png inputs.
 * @param baseImage The image to check.
 * @return True if opaque, false otherwise.
 */
bool IsImageOpaque(const Image& baseImage) {
    // if the image has no alpha channel, we're done now
    if (!baseImage.alpha())
        return true;

    // if it does not work that simple, we need to check the alpha channel for non-opaque values
    // it seems to be best practice to clone the image beforehand
    Image img(baseImage);

    // find image width and height for iteration
    int imgWidth = img.columns();
    int imgHeight = img.rows();

    // iterate the whole image
    for ( int row = 0; row <= imgHeight; row++ )
    {
        for ( int column = 0; column <= imgWidth; column++ )
        {
            // get each pixel
            Color px = img.pixelColor( column, row );
            // opaque means that the alpha channel has the max value, so if we find a pixel where this condition is not
            // met, the image is not opaque
            if (px.quantumAlpha() != QuantumRange)
                return false;
        }
    }

    // if we did not exit early, we did not find a transparent pixel and, therefore, the image is opaque
    // note that we did *not* check for other transparency methods, such as a color which is marked as transparent (gif
    // uses this AFAIK), so be vary for inputs other than png or jpg.
    return true;
}
```